# Reverse order using command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sorting, command-line

Is there a way i use the `ps --sort` option on a linux to display the processes in reverse order based on the process ID or is there another command i can use for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ascending:

```
ps ax --sort +pid
```

Descending

```
ps ax --sort -pid
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the Linux `ps` command we're discussing,

```
ps --sort='-pid'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also for sorting the pid

```
ps -ax | sort -n
```

---

`ps -ax` is for display all process with pid. `sort -n` for numeric sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tac` command also

> tac command print files in reverse

---

```
ps -aux --sort -pid
```

and

```
ps -aux | tac
```